# How to insert more dialogs in MFC Dialog application?

Tags: c++, mfc, dialog

I am trying to build an MFC application Dialog based application. It runs ok. But I need to insert another Dialog. So how can I for example, pressing on a button from the first dialog to open the new added dialog?.

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2015.

- I right clicked on the resources folder and insert a dialog.

It is inserted, but how to create it?.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way is: I consider you are creating a Dialog based application so you get a main Dialog box and an About Dialog box when Selecting menu->About.

- To add Another Dialog to your application:

1- Right click on the solution explorer on the resources files and select Add->Resource->Dialog->New

You get a new Dialog right front of you. Right click on this Dialog and select Add Class. give it for example a name like "MyDlg2" and click ok.

You'll see two files added: `MyDlg2.h` and `MyDlg2.cpp`.

Now How to Popup this second dialog (MyDlg2)? Let's create a button on the main Dialog:

- Drag a button onto Main Dialog.
- Give it a caption "Gong to Dialog2..."
- Double-click this button to add a handler for it.
- In this handler enter:

  ```
  MyDlg2 dlg;
  dlg.DoModal();
  ```
- Scroll to the top of this file and add:

  ```
  #include "MyDlg2.h"
  ```

This is important so that main Dialog knows How to create dialog 2.

- Build and run.

Answer (score 1):

You need to derive a class from CDialog. 
For more information check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wb9s9ah.aspx) MSDN example.